# Unable to install Wordpress through filezilla

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to install WordPress using Filezilla. I am getting 404 error and hence, I am unable to install it. The only access I have is though Filezilla. I create an index.html file to test for access in the root folder and the output was displayed correctly. Hence, I copied WordPress files there and got 404 Error. Can it be an issue with the database? 
My website URL is bharattourists.com

Comment: Your site is redirecting to : http://bharattourists.com/bharattourists.com/wp-admin/setup-config.html. I suggest you delete everything that is in public_html folder (only in case it is only your site located on this server) and upload again the unzipped content from the wordpress zip file you have downloaded from wordpress.org

Answer (score 0):

It may be file permission issue, check your files should having 644 permission and all directories have 755 permission